# How do I unit test stateChange callback from the component in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I am writing unit tests and want to test state change callback from the component.

Unit Test code

```
import React from 'react';
import {configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import NameTextField from './NameTextField';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {createShallow} from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('<NameTextField />', () => {
  let shallow;

  beforeAll(() => {
    shallow = createShallow();
  });
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<NameTextField onStateChange={handleStateChange}/>);
  });


  const handleStateChange = updatedState => {
  };


  it('should show no error when correctly entered', () => {
    const handleStateChange = jest.fn()

    act(() => {
      wrapper.find(TextField).at(0).simulate('blur', {target: {value: 'correct name'}});
    });
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find(TextField).at(0).props().error).toBe(
        false);
    expect(wrapper.find(TextField).at(0).props().helperText).toBe(
        null);
    expect(handleStateChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10')

  });

});
```

I have NameTextField component here where depending on it's input on Textfield, I get onStateChange callback.

```
<NameTextField onStateChange={handleStateChange}/>
```

When I test using

```
    expect(handleStateChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10')
```

I get error message saying

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

Expected mock function to have been called with:
  ["10"]
But it was not called.
```

How would I capture the stateChange callback on the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer as soon as I posted here.

Simple mistake.

```
import React from 'react';
import {configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import NameTextField from './NameTextField';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import {createShallow} from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';
import {act} from 'react-dom/test-utils';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('<NameTextField />', () => {
  let shallow;

  beforeAll(() => {
    shallow = createShallow();
  });
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<NameTextField onStateChange={handleStateChange}/>);
  });


    const handleStateChange = jest.fn();


  it('should show no error when correctly entered', () => {

    act(() => {
      wrapper.find(TextField).at(0).simulate('blur', {target: {value: 'correct name'}});
    });
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find(TextField).at(0).props().error).toBe(
        false);
    expect(wrapper.find(TextField).at(0).props().helperText).toBe(
        null);
    expect(handleStateChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10')

  });

});
```

const handleStateChange = jest.fn();

there was duplicate handleStateChange.